# How can you see how many lives you have in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can you see how many lives you have in Minecraft?

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft has only two categories **Unlimited lives:** Which would be creative mode, survival mode, and adventure mode.  Or **One life:** which would be Hardcore mode:  Although you may die, in most game modes you will be given the option to revive.

Answer (score 2):

In Vanilla Minecraft, you have an infinite amount of lives, so naturally - There is no limit on how many deaths you can do*.
In Hardcore Mode however, you only have one life, and that life is determined whether you're still playing or staring at a <kbd>Delete World</kbd> button.

For mods, such as Hardcore Questing Mode, you can find your remaining lives in the front page of the quest book.

*Assuming you're not using any command blocks or mods.

---

As for the number of times you have died, you can display it in the scoreboard like so:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Deaths stat.deaths Deaths
/scoreboard objectives setDisplay sidebar Deaths
```

or you can find it in the Statistics menu.